# Getting 405 when trying to post a comment

Tags: support, javascript, comments, node.js

I'm trying to post a comment to [The API Sandbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/51812/the-api-sandbox), I did one using the [interactive documentation](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/create-comment), but when trying to use my own code, it doesn't work. Instead, I get status code 405 (Method not allowed)

```
const http = require("http")
let req = http.request({
    method: "POST",
    href: `https://api.stackexchange.com/2.3/posts/51812/comments/add?site=meta&access_token=my_access_token&key=app_key&body=${encodeURI("Testing comment with enough length")}&preview=false`,
    headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
    }
}, res => {
    console.log(`code: ${res.statusCode}`) // "code: 405"
    res.on("error", console.error)
})
req.end()
```

I don't really understand how I'm supposed to post the comment. Did I make a mistake?

Removing `method: "POST"` gives status code 200, but still doesn't post a comment.

Also, when using `res.on("data")`, for some reason it sends back this webpage:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>IIS 10.0 Detailed Error - 405.0 - Method Not Allowed</title>
<style type="text/css">
<!--
body{margin:0;font-size:.7em;font-family:Verdana,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;}
code{margin:0;color:#006600;font-size:1.1em;font-weight:bold;}
.config_source code{font-size:.8em;color:#000000;}
pre{margin:0;font-size:1.4em;word-wrap:break-word;}
ul,ol{margin:10px 0 10px 5px;}
ul.first,ol.first{margin-top:5px;}
fieldset{padding:0 15px 10px 15px;word-break:break-all;}
.summary-container fieldset{padding-bottom:5px;margin-top:4px;}
legend.no-expand-all{padding:2px 15px 4px 10px;margin:0 0 0 -12px;}
legend{color:#333333;;margin:4px 0 8px -12px;_margin-top:0px;
font-weight:bold;font-size:1em;}
a:link,a:visited{color:#007EFF;font-weight:bold;}
a:hover{text-decoration:none;}
h1{font-size:2.4em;margin:0;color:#FFF;}
h2{font-size:1.7em;margin:0;color:#CC0000;}
h3{font-size:1.4em;margin:10px 0 0 0;color:#CC0000;}
h4{font-size:1.2em;margin:10px 0 5px 0;
}#header{width:96%;margin:0 0 0 0;padding:6px 2% 6px 2%;font-family:"trebuchet MS",Verdana,sans-serif;       
 color:#FFF;background-color:#5C87B2;
}#content{margin:0 0 0 2%;position:relative;}
.summary-container,.content-container{background:#FFF;width:96%;margin-top:8px;padding:10px;position:relative;}
.content-container p{margin:0 0 10px 0;
}#details-left{width:35%;float:left;margin-right:2%;
}#details-right{width:63%;float:left;overflow:hidden;
}#server_version{width:96%;_height:1px;min-height:1px;margin:0 0 5px 0;padding:11px 2% 8px 2%;color:#FFFFFF; 
 background-color:#5A7FA5;border-bottom:1px solid #C1CFDD;border-top:1px solid #4A6C8E;font-weight:normal;   
 font-size:1em;color:#FFF;text-align:right;
}#server_version p{margin:5px 0;}
table{margin:4px 0 4px 0;width:100%;border:none;}
td,th{vertical-align:top;padding:3px 0;text-align:left;font-weight:normal;border:none;}
th{width:30%;text-align:right;padding-right:2%;font-weight:bold;}
thead th{background-color:#ebebeb;width:25%;
}#details-right th{width:20%;}
table tr.alt td,table tr.alt th{}
.highlight-code{color:#CC0000;font-weight:bold;font-style:italic;}
.clear{clear:both;}
.preferred{padding:0 5px 2px 5px;font-weight:normal;background:#006633;color:#FFF;font-size:.8em;}
-->
</style>

</head>
<body>
<div id="content">
<div class="content-container">
  <h3>HTTP Error 405.0 - Method Not Allowed</h3>
  <h4>The page you are looking for cannot be displayed because an invalid method (HTTP verb) is being used.</h4>
</div>
<div class="content-container">
 <fieldset><h4>Most likely causes:</h4>
  <ul>  <li>The request sent to the Web server used an HTTP verb that is not allowed by the module configured to handle the request.</li>    <li>A request was sent to the server that contained an invalid HTTP verb.</li>       <li>The request is for static content and contains an HTTP verb other than GET or HEAD.</li>    <li>A request was sent to a virtual directory using the HTTP verb POST and the default document is a static file that does not support HTTP verbs other than GET or HEAD.</li> </ul>
 </fieldset>
</div>
<div class="content-container">
 <fieldset><h4>Things you can try:</h4>
  <ul>  <li>Verify the list of verbs enabled for the module handler this request was sent to, and ensure that this verb should be allowed for the Web site.</li>     <li>Check the IIS log file to see which verb is not allowed for the request.</li>    <li>Create a tracing rule to track failed requests for this HTTP status code. For more information about creating a tracing rule for failed requests, click <a href="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=66439">here</a>. </li> </ul>
 </fieldset>
</div>

<div class="content-container">
 <fieldset><h4>Detailed Error Information:</h4>
  <div id="details-left">
   <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr class="alt"><th>Module</th><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;StaticFileModule</td></tr>
    <tr><th>Notification</th><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;ExecuteRequestHandler</td></tr>
    <tr class="alt"><th>Handler</th><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;StaticFile</td></tr>
    <tr><th>Error Code</th><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;0x80070001</td></tr>

   </table>
  </div>
  <div id="details-right">
   <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr class="alt"><th>Requested URL</th><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;http://localhost:80/iisstart.htm</td></tr>   
    <tr><th>Physical Path</th><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;C:\inetpub\wwwroot\iisstart.htm</td></tr>
    <tr class="alt"><th>Logon Method</th><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Anonymous</td></tr>
    <tr><th>Logon User</th><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Anonymous</td></tr>

   </table>
   <div class="clear"></div>
  </div>
 </fieldset>
</div>

<div class="content-container">
 <fieldset><h4>More Information:</h4>
  This error means that the request sent to the Web server contained an HTTP verb that is not allowed by the 
configured module handler for the request.
  <p><a href="https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=62293&amp;IIS70Error=405,0,0x80070001,19044">View more 
information &raquo;</a></p>

 </fieldset>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

However, switching to `GET` shows this instead:

```
<!--
body {
        color:#000000;
        background-color:#0072C6;
        margin:0;
}

#container {
        margin-left:auto;
        margin-right:auto;
        text-align:center;
        }

a img {
        border:none;
}

-->
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container">
<a href="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=66138&amp;clcid=0x409"><img src="iisstart.png" alt="IIS" width="960" height="600" /></a>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was the fact that I was using the http module, rather than https. Since its protocol is https, I have to use the https module

```js
const https = require("https")
const data = `site=meta&access_token=my_access_token&key=app_key&body=${encodeURI("Testing comment with enough length")}&preview=false`
let req = https.request({
    method: "POST",
    hostname: `api.stackexchange.com`,
    path: "/2.3/posts/51812/comments/add",
    port: 443
    headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    }
}, res => {
    console.log(`code: ${res.statusCode}`) // "code: 200" and comment posted
    res.on("error", console.error)
})
req.write(data)
req.end()
```

Comment: Thanks for finding the solution, and reminding me why I don't like node.js - I mean *why on Earth* would you use different clients for HTTP and HTTPS ... I'll cleanup the comments under the question since they don't serve any purpose.

Comment: @Glorfindel I think this is a bit unfair to Node.js to consider importing the wrong core package for the job to be a flaw on the part of the runtime - HTTPS is HTTP *over* TLS, which is an extension of the protocol, so it makes sense to provide both HTTP and HTTPS clients in case the former is required by the end-user.

Comment: @OlegValter OK, let me phrase my criticism differently. If the HTTP client doesn't support HTTPS, why doesn't it throw an exception with a meaningful error message? (OTOH, we should probably have this discussion in a chatroom ...)

Comment: @Glorfindel I think sending back `418` would perfectly represent requesting an HTTPS-only server via HTTP :) I am not sure why would the module throw an exception, though, as it is low-level (which is explicitly documented), and it is the onus of the server to return an appropriate HTTP status code and message when a client makes a request. The module does its job well: the client gets back a `405` response. A better question is why *this one*? And now I am also curious about what is the content of the `Allow` header sent back as it *must* be set when returning a `405` response.

Comment: That said, I am not sure what status code *should* be sent by the API to express the "please use HTTPS" requirement - `429` does not seem to cut it as it is mostly reserved to WebSocket and HTTP/1.1 to HTTP/2 upgrades and `505` is basically the same thing. I guess sending a `Upgrade-Insecure-Requests` header with a request is an option, but that is on the end-user to supply too.

Comment: always happy to drop by to [a room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/27/stack-apps) to have a duel to the death on the merits of Node.js, though, to avoid cluttering the comment section :)